# Replotting result of find_contours onto a different grid

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have used the skimage find_contours on some velocity data but I am struggling to work out how to replot the contour outline onto a longitude latitude grid ?
[image: find_contours on the raw velocity data]

[image: Red and blue contours are the velocity and the solid black line is the result of the find_contours.]

I think it is some sort of transform in coordinates but I am struggling to work out how.